# Pointer to children window/s in x11

Tags: c, x11, xlib

How to obtain the pointer to the child window/s form the root window in x11 ?
I have used the XGetWindowAttributes(), but that doesn't have any pointer/s to children windows as such. 
https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowAttributes.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `XQueryTree()` in order to get a list of children from any window.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21757291)

Comment: @oguzismail The question is very open, but without knowing any background I'm not in a position to debate the question as such.  To get a list of children you use XQueryTree().  There is nothing more or less to the answer.

Comment: @FrodeTennebo In fact this is not what I am looking for. I want to know if there is a window property that is a pointer to the child windows. I don't want to print the children of a window.

Comment: @Bmsbharadwaj There is no window property that is a pointer to the child windows. You have to query the tree, which is what XQueryTree() does.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, I found out (as far as I have researched) that there is no such thing as pointer to windows in window properties.

My main aim was to make a child of one window, say w1, as the child of another window, say w2. So I wanted to know if we can do this using window pointers.
But later I discovered that this can be simply achieved using XReparentWindow() function, as given here:

https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-and-session-manager/XReparentWindow.html

Anyways, @FrodeTennebo, thanks for the concept of [XQueryTree()](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryTree.html), which can be used to print all the children of a specific window.

Comment: For future reference, please go straight for your main aim, and not via what you believe is the question. There are lots of other uses for `XQueryTree()` than printing the tree. Actually, that's the least useful use as there is already a tool for that in the form of `xwininfo -tree`. As to switching the parent of a window, `XReparentWindow()`is the correct method.